# How to remotely update azure webapp firewall with local IP via powershell or C#

Tags: c#, powershell, azure, azure-sql-database, firewall

How can I remotely update my azure webapp firewall with my local PCs IP address for administration either via powershell or C#.

I have had a look over the documentation but I can only find out how to do it from the actual server itself, not remotely.

I can get visual studio to pop up and ask me if I want to add my IP address to the firewall randomly, but most the time it simply fails and does not ask me so I am looking for a solution other than manually logging into the azure portal whenever my IP address changes.

Looking for either an example or a link to documentation that shows which libraries to use.

**Update: I tried Tom Suns answer however we are using a web app not an sql server so it does not work.**

azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup("resourcegroup","webapp")

returns the web app but I cannot find anyway to programatically access the "Access Restrictions" found under networking for this web app.

I also can only access the main deployment slot for this web app. I need to set the firewall individually per deployment slot (as can be done via the azure web interface).

I have tried accessing the second deployment slot via the following names, all return null. This is assuming the web app is named 'webapp' and the deployment slot is named 'slo1'

webapp-slot1
webapp_slot1
webapp/slot1

I have also tried GetByID instead of GetByResourceGroup however I cannot find any examples of what he ID is and where it can be found. I've tried almost every single ID I can find on the azure web UI.

Finally Tom Sun's answer requires hard coded credentials being stored on a drive. This is far from optimal. I would prefer a popup UI that prompts the user for their username and password, this used to be possible with older versions of the API however everything I can find says it is no longer. I may have to resort to powershell.

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it that  will help more communities who have the same issue easily to search.

Comment: @TomSun-MSFT I have finally got back to trying this and I cannot get any of the solutions to work.

Answer (score 5):

We can do that with [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/),more detail info about library, please refer to the packages.config. We also could get more [demo code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/Samples/Sql/ManageSqlFirewallRules.cs) from the [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/tree/master/Samples). Before coding we need to registry an Azure AD Application and assign corresponding role for it, more details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal#create-an-active-directory-application). Then we can get the clientId, key(secret key) and tenant from the Azure AD App. After that we could create the [Auth file](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#auth-file-formats) with following format

```
subscription=########-####-####-####-############
client=########-####-####-####-############
tenant=########-####-####-####-############
key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
managementURI=https\://management.core.windows.net/
baseURL=https\://management.azure.com/
authURL=https\://login.windows.net/
graphURL=https\://graph.windows.net/
```

**Demo code:**

```
 var credFile = @"File Path"; // example: c:\tom\auth.txt
            var resourceGroup = "resource group";
            var azureSQLServer = "Azure sql server name"; //just name of the Azure sql server such as tomdemo
            var firewallRull = "firewall rull name";//such as myFirewallRull
            var firewallRuleIPAddress = "x.x.x.x";//your Ip address
            var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(credFile);
            var azure = Azure
                .Configure()
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .Authenticate(credentials)
                .WithDefaultSubscription();

            var sqlServer = azure.SqlServers.GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroup, azureSQLServer);
            var newFirewallRule = sqlServer.FirewallRules.Define(firewallRull)
                .WithIPAddress(firewallRuleIPAddress)
                .Create();
```

**packages.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Core" version="1.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.AppService.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Batch.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Cdn.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerInstance.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerRegistry.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.CosmosDB.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Graph.RBAC.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.KeyVault.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Network.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Redis.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.Storage.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Azure.Management.TrafficManager.Fluent" version="1.3.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Edm" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.OData" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Data.Services.Client" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory" version="2.28.3" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime" version="2.3.9" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure" version="3.3.10" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Rest.ClientRuntime.Azure.Authentication" version="2.3.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="6.0.8" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Dynamic.Runtime" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Linq.Queryable" version="4.0.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Net.Requests" version="4.0.11" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="System.Spatial" version="5.8.2" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="WindowsAzure.Storage" version="8.1.4" targetFramework="net461" />
</packages>
```

Comment: Is the credfile another name for auth file?

Comment: `credfile`  is the path of auth file including the auth file name.

Comment: This only works for SQL Servers. I have a webapp that I accessed via 'azure.WebApps.GetByResourceGroup' however there is no way I can find to programatically modify the "Access restrictions" for the webapp. I also cannot find how to access individual deployment slots on the web app. I've tried webapp/deploymentslot webapp_deploymentslot webapp-deploymentslot and even directly by ID but it always returns null. Only the master/main web app seems to be accessible.

Answer (score 1):

For PowerShell, you would need to use [`New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.sql/new-azurermsqlserverfirewallrule?view=azurermps-4.4.0).

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure#manage-firewall-rules-using-azure-powershell):

> New-AzureRmSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName "myResourceGroup"
>   
>       `-ServerName $servername`
>       -FirewallRuleName "AllowSome" -StartIpAddress "0.0.0.0" -EndIpAddress "0.0.0.0"

Comment: How do I authenticate? How does it know know my azure subscription username and password?

Comment: You will start with `Login-AzureRmAccount` to authenticate yourself.

Comment: @GauravMantri This will work when you are manually logged via powershell. But may not help for automation.

Answer (score 1):

From C# you can access all Azure resources via [Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) like this

```
// Create an authentication context to Azure and acquire a login token
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId");
var auth = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
                    "yourClientId", new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
                    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
string token = auth.AccessToken;
var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(tokenCredentials, tokenCredentials, 
                           AzureParts.Tenant, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

// Build the client with the acquired token as a credential.
RestClient client = RestClient.Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .WithCredentials(azureCredentials)
                .Build();

// Authenticate against azure with the correct subscription to access.
var azure = Azure.Authenticate(client, AzureParts.Tenant)
                .WithSubscription("subscriptionId");

// Search for the sql server and add a firewall rule.
var sqlServer = azure.SqlServers.GetByResourceGroup("ResourceGroup", "servername");
sqlServer.FirewallRules.Define("LetMeIn").WithIPAddress("yourIp").Create();
```

Note that acquiring the login token via `AcquireTokenAsync` will open a login window and thus can not be used in an automated fashion. You could provide a token-cache with an already stored token if you want to only login once.

A more complex example to retrieve the token without a token-cache (see the overloads for the `AuthenticationContext` constructor if you want to add a token cache):

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>", false);
AuthenticationResult authResult = null;

try
{
    authResult = await context.AcquireTokenSilentAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/", clientId);
}
catch (AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
{
    authResult = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.core.windows.net/",
    clientId, new Uri("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"),
    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
}
string token = authResult.AccessToken;
```

Comment: Can you please list all packages, using statements and show your nuget configuration. These answers can be really frustrating when you have to spend 1 hour figuring out what environment (netstandard or netcore) what nuget version etc etc was required for this to build and work.

Comment: Also where does token come from? It isn't even defined in your example...

Comment: @rolls I added a more complex example for the token retrieval and fixed the missing token in the original code, you only need the Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent package.

Comment: Thanks @GaussZ Is it possible to modify the example to work for an azure WebApp "access restriction" firewall instead of an SQL server?

Comment: @rolls I don't have a web app to test that at the moment but you should be able to access what you need from here: (await azure.WebApps.GetByIdAsync("id")).Inner.SiteConfig.IpSecurityRestrictions