# Why is my Azure public IP not showing up in Dns.GetHostAddresses?

Tags: c#, azure, dns, azure-virtual-machine

I'm trying to set up a custom server on an Azure VM.  I've assigned it a public IP address, which I'm able to reach and get into the server via Remote Desktop, so that part's working just fine.

But when I try to bind to the public IP address using [the websocket-sharp library](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp), it fails, saying "the host part isn't a local host name."

I've tracked this down to [this file](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp/blob/master/websocket-sharp/Ext.cs), where the following code block executes, and ends up returning false:

```
  var host = System.Net.Dns.GetHostName ();
  var addrs = System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses (host);
  foreach (var addr in addrs) {
    if (address.Equals (addr))
      return true;
  }

return false;
```

With a bit of debugging, I've determined that `Dns.GetHostAddresses` is showing internal IPs only, but not the external IP address.  I've configured the IP address in Azure and attached it to the server, and I've turned on IP forwarding in the networking configuration and rebooted the VM, but the server still doesn't recognize its own external IP.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's by design. It simply cannot see public IP due to computer networking design. You should simply bind to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Is there any update about  this?

Answer (score 0):

> What am I missing?

You could test **Dns.GetHostAddresses** with the local machine hostname, it also just could get the **internal** ip,  it is not related to Azure VM.

If we want to get the public Ip of Azure VM with host name, we could use the Azure SDK to do that.

I also do a sample demo to get the public IP. Before that we need to registry Azure AD and assign corrosponding role to registried App. About how to registry Azure AD and create creditial file, you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46616782/how-to-remotely-update-azure-sql-firewall-with-local-ip-via-powershell-or-c-shar/46617099#46617099)  and this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net/blob/master/AUTH.md#auth-file-formats).

```
var subscriptiondId = "subscription Id";
var credentials =  SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"path of creditial file");
var resouceGroup = "resouce group";
var hostName = "host name";
NetworkManagementClient networkManagement = new NetworkManagementClient(credentials) { SubscriptionId = subscriptiondId };
ComputeManagementClient computeManagement =
new ComputeManagementClient(credentials) {SubscriptionId = subscriptiondId};
var nic = computeManagement.VirtualMachines.GetAsync(resouceGroup, hostName).Result.NetworkProfile.NetworkInterfaces
            .FirstOrDefault();
var networkIntefaceName = nic?.Id.Split('/').Last();
var ipConfiguration  = networkManagement.NetworkInterfaces.GetAsync(resouceGroup, networkIntefaceName).Result.IpConfigurations.FirstOrDefault();
var publicIpAddressId = ipConfiguration?.PublicIPAddress.Id;
var ip = networkManagement.PublicIPAddresses.GetAsync(resouceGroup, publicIpAddressId?.Split('/').Last()
```

[image]